# Laptop power button seems to be disconnected

Tags: laptop, power-supply, power, asus

I've always had this issue with my laptop where it needs the power to be drained from the motherboard before it can start normally (7 year old laptop). And I've learned to do the whole, pressing down the power button for a few seconds while unplugged AC/Battery, but now when I press down the power button it doesn't seem to do anything.

My laptop auto starts when the AC plugs in and usually it'll turn the power button light on, turn the keyboard lights on for just a second and then nothing happens, ot just refuses to boot normally until I hold the power button to shut it down, unplug it, hold the power button for a few seconds and there we go, it'll boot normally after plugging the AC again. But now holding the power button doesn't seem to shut it down anymore, nor does it even seem to have any effect when I want to drain power. Is my laptop keyboard dead? I've opened it and checked that all the keyboard wires are securely in place and not disconnected. Anything else I need to check?

EDIT: I guess I need a new keyboard, in the mean time, anyone know how to drain flea power without using the power button?

Comment: If the power button is on the keyboard, it is reasonable to assume (since connections are fine) that you need to replace the keyboard. I had to do that on my X230 laptop. I could tell in my fingers that the button had gone soft. See if that is true for you.

Comment: Ah yeah, I just tried comparing the button press and it's not obvious but it certainly doesn't feel the same as pressing other buttons. welp guess I'll look into getting another keyboard, thanks @john

Comment: I posted an answer (since this is a Q&A forum). You have confirmed. So I trust you will accept the solution    to @NotAProgrammer

Answer (score 0):

I had to do that on my X230 laptop. I could tell in my fingers that the button had gone soft. I replaced the keyboard and it is working fine.

If the power button is on the keyboard, it is reasonable to assume (since connections are fine) that you need to replace the keyboard.